# Hard Differential Equation. Please help.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, physics, classical-mechanics

first of all I'm not a mathematician, so I apologize if any of my understanding and terminology isn't up to par.  Also, I've never used this website (or any of these kind of question/answer) websites before, hope it works.

I'm a mech. eng having trouble with a differential equation that is crucial to my research in graduate school.  I've spend a long time trying to look up and understand tons of sources anything from books to buddies around the college.

---

This is the differential equation:

$$
\dfrac{F(t)}{\left(\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\right)^2+1}=c^2y^2\left(\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}\right)^2
$$

I'm trying to solve for y which I THINK is dependent on x only, but i'm not sure.  It could be y(x) or y(t). I also think this is a 1st order non-linear non-homogenous DE, but again I'm not sure.  I initially thought it might be a partial differential equation though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try rewriting $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$.

Comment: I think you should clarify a little bit: Do you want to find $y(x)$, $x(t)$ or $y(x(t))$?